# Custom position of an arrow in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{decument}
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (pro1)[process, below of=in1]{Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces : 
[image]

But I wat :

[image]

How can I draw this diagram?

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. Please correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place an auxiliary coordinate in the mid-point of the arrow from `pro1` to `dec1`

```
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- coordinate[midway] (aux) (dec1);
```

and then use this coordinate to draw the arrow:

```
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (aux);
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
startstop/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em},
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (in1) {};
\node (pro1)[process, below = of in1]{Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below = of pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\node (pro2b) [process, right = of dec1] {Process 2b};

\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- coordinate[midway] (aux) (dec1);
%\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2b);
%\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- I changed the original code. I used the more convenient `\tikzset` syntax instead of the old `\tikzstyle`
- I also added a missing coordinate and commented out parts of the code that were producing errors since some nodes were not defined.
- I changed the old `of=` syntax to the more convenient `=of` for node positioning, with the help of the `positioning` library.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a coordinate midway along the arrow between process 1 and decision 1 as follows. You should also change the use of `\tikzstyle`, which is deprecated, to `\tikzset`, and use the new syntax provided by the `positioning` library i.e. `below=of ...` rather than `below of=...`. Finally, `arrows.meta` replaces `arrows`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    startstop/.style = {draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,minimum height=2em},
    io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    decision/.style = {diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\coordinate (in1);
\node (pro1)[process, below=of in1]{Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below=of pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\coordinate [below=of dec1] (pro2a);
\node (pro2b) [process, right=of dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1) coordinate [midway] (mid1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (mid1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrow midway]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\psset{fillstyle = solid, arrows = ->}
\begin{pspicture}(7.5,7.5)
  \psline(1.5,7.5)(1.5,6.5)
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange!40](0,5)(3,6.5)
  \rput(1.5,5.75){Process~1}
  \psline(1.5,5)(1.5,4)
  \pspolygon[fillcolor = green!40](0,2.5)(1.5,4)(3,2.5)(1.5,1)
  \rput(1.5,2.5){Decision~1}
  \psline(1.5,1)(1.5,0)
  \rput(1.15,0.5){yes}
  \psline(3,2.5)(4.5,2.5)
  \rput(3.75,2.7){no}
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange!40](4.5,1.75)(7.5,3.25)
  \rput(6,2.5){Process~2b}
  \psline(6,3.25)(6,4.5)(1.5,4.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]